# Changing "Reset password token is invalid" message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

After old reset password token is used, I get an error:

```
1 error prohibited this user from being saved:
Reset password token is invalid
```

Where can I modify the message `Reset password token is invalid` in Devise, Rails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Devise controller is hidden from you, unless you have specifically added it into your app. Here is the documentation from Devise about extending functionality of the controller:

You can completely override a controller action:

```
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  def create
    *Put your custom code and flash message here*
  end
```

Or you can simply add new behaviour to it:

```
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  def create
    super do |resource|
      BackgroundWorker.trigger(resource)
    end
  end
end
```

Here is the Devise documentation: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

Comment: this doesn't answer the question

Answer (score 0):

laravel 5.2 go to :

```
resources/lang/en/..
```

`/..` is your file .php
ex :

auth.php

pagination.php

password.php

validation.php

```
<?php



/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Validation Language Lines
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The following language lines contain the default error messages used by
| the validator class. Some of these rules have multiple versions such
| as the size rules. Feel free to tweak each of these messages here.
|
*/

'accepted'             => 'The :attribute must be accepted.',
'active_url'           => 'The :attribute is not a valid URL.',
'after'                => 'The :attribute must be a date after :date.',
'alpha'                => 'The :attribute may only contain letters.',
'alpha_dash'           => 'The :attribute may only contain letters, numbers, and dashes.',
'alpha_num'            => 'The :attribute may only contain letters and numbers.',
'array'                => 'The :attribute must be an array.',
'before'               => 'The :attribute must be a date before :date.',
'between'              => [
    'numeric' => 'The :attribute must be between :min and :max.',
    'file'    => 'The :attribute must be between :min and :max kilobytes.',
    'string'  => 'The :attribute must be between :min and :max characters.',
    'array'   => 'The :attribute must have between :min and :max items.',
],
'boolean'              => 'The :attribute field must be true or false.',
'confirmed'            => 'The :attribute confirmation does not match.',
'date'                 => 'The :attribute is not a valid date.',
'date_format'          => 'The :attribute does not match the format :format.',
'different'            => 'The :attribute and :other must be different.',
'digits'               => 'The :attribute must be :digits digits.',
'digits_between'       => 'The :attribute must be between :min and :max digits.',
'dimensions'           => 'The :attribute has invalid image dimensions.',
'distinct'             => 'The :attribute field has a duplicate value.',
'email'                => 'The :attribute must be a valid email address.',
'exists'               => 'The selected :attribute is invalid.',
'filled'               => 'The :attribute field is required.',
'image'                => 'The :attribute must be an image.',
'in'                   => 'The selected :attribute is invalid.',
'in_array'             => 'The :attribute field does not exist in :other.',
'integer'              => 'The :attribute must be an integer.',
'ip'                   => 'The :attribute must be a valid IP address.',
'json'                 => 'The :attribute must be a valid JSON string.',
'max'                  => [
    'numeric' => 'The :attribute may not be greater than :max.',
    'file'    => 'The :attribute may not be greater than :max kilobytes.',
    'string'  => 'The :attribute may not be greater than :max characters.',
    'array'   => 'The :attribute may not have more than :max items.',
],
'mimes'                => 'The :attribute must be a file of type: :values.',
'min'                  => [
    'numeric' => 'The :attribute must be at least :min.',
    'file'    => 'The :attribute must be at least :min kilobytes.',
    'string'  => 'The :attribute must be at least :min characters.',
    'array'   => 'The :attribute must have at least :min items.',
],
'not_in'               => 'The selected :attribute is invalid.',
'numeric'              => 'The :attribute must be a number.',
'present'              => 'The :attribute field must be present.',
'regex'                => 'The :attribute format is invalid.',
'required'             => 'info! :attribute tidak boleh kosong.',
'required_if'          => 'The :attribute field is required when :other is :value.',
'required_unless'      => 'The :attribute field is required unless :other is in :values.',
'required_with'        => 'The :attribute field is required when :values is present.',
'required_with_all'    => 'The :attribute field is required when :values is present.',
'required_without'     => 'The :attribute field is required when :values is not present.',
'required_without_all' => 'The :attribute field is required when none of :values are present.',
'same'                 => 'The :attribute and :other must match.',
'size'                 => [
    'numeric' => 'The :attribute must be :size.',
    'file'    => 'The :attribute must be :size kilobytes.',
    'string'  => 'The :attribute must be :size characters.',
    'array'   => 'The :attribute must contain :size items.',
],
'string'               => 'The :attribute must be a string.',
'timezone'             => 'The :attribute must be a valid zone.',
'unique'               => 'The :attribute has already been taken.',
'url'                  => 'The :attribute format is invalid.',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Custom Validation Language Lines
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify custom validation messages for attributes using the
| convention "attribute.rule" to name the lines. This makes it quick to
| specify a specific custom language line for a given attribute rule.
|
*/

'custom' => [
    'attribute-name' => [
        'rule-name' => 'custom-message',
    ],
],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Custom Validation Attributes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The following language lines are used to swap attribute place-holders
| with something more reader friendly such as E-Mail Address instead
| of "email". This simply helps us make messages a little cleaner.
|
*/

'attributes' => [],];
```

Comment: this is clearly about devise, in ruby on rails framework. how a PHP answer would be useful?